# How to create a collapsible panel in WPF

Tags: wpf, panel, collapsiblepanelextender

I am creating a Windows application (WPF) and C#. In my view, I have to add few layouts like browsing a folder, displaying the files in the folder in a list view...etc

My requirement is :
The panels mentioned above should be collapsible panels, I guess, we dont have option of collapsible panel in wpf.

I have to create a custom control for this? If so, Please suggest me how to do this?

Comment: Vaccano, bad form.

Comment: @Vaccano: the answer has been accepted, you should remove your downvote now

Answer (score 71, accepted):

The Expander control may  be what you are looking for. From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.expander.aspx):

> Expander Class
>
> Represents the control that displays a header that has a collapsible window that displays content.

Comment: Thanks for the link.
But this doesn't look like a collapsible panel in ASP.NET.
Actually I am not using ASP.NET controls in my proj. But if I want that kind of control in WPF, how can this be acheived?
Pls help me
Thanks
Ramm

Comment: I am not sure what you mean - Expander *is* a WPF control and does seem to behave like a collapsible panel. Can you please explain what functionality you are missing?

Answer (score 10):

May like this?

```
 <Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="2*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Border  Background="Red" Height="12" VerticalAlignment="Top" MouseEnter="StackPanel_MouseEnter" MouseLeave="StackPanel_MouseLeave"></Border>
</Grid>
```

C# code behind

```
 private void StackPanel_MouseEnter(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        Border sp = sender as Border;
        DoubleAnimation db = new DoubleAnimation();
        //db.From = 12;
        db.To = 150;
        db.Duration = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0.5);
        db.AutoReverse = false;
        db.RepeatBehavior = new RepeatBehavior(1);
        sp.BeginAnimation(StackPanel.HeightProperty, db);
    }

    private void StackPanel_MouseLeave(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        Border sp = sender as Border;
        DoubleAnimation db = new DoubleAnimation();
        //db.From = 12;
        db.To = 12;
        db.Duration = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0.5);
        db.AutoReverse = false;
        db.RepeatBehavior = new RepeatBehavior(1);
        sp.BeginAnimation(StackPanel.HeightProperty, db);
    }
}
```

You can use any element control like grid, stack, dock, border ...

Comment: How about an example using the VisualStateManager?