# WPF DataGrid in ComboBox

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I'm trying to add DataGrid inside a ComboBox to try save screen space on complexed window.

Here is my code:

```
<ComboBox Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" >
    <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Path=ProductList, Source={StaticResource MainWindowViewModel}}" AutoGenerateColumns="false" Width="500" Height="80">
                <DataGrid.Columns>
                    <DataGridCheckBoxColumn Header="Selected" IsReadOnly="False" />
                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Name" Binding="{Binding Name}" Width="100" />
                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Code" Binding="{Binding Code}" Width="100" />
                </DataGrid.Columns>
            </DataGrid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
    <Separator/>
</ComboBox>
```

Separator is just hack so there will be one object in combobox so it will show the datagrid.
Problem being is that I can't select the row or even tick the checkboxs.

If anyone has any suggestions that be great. Cheers.

Comment: DataGrid inside a Combobox? Do you mean something like collapsible panel?

Comment: Yup, that's right. Best way I thought would be viable would be DataGrid inside a ComboBox, unless you have better alternative.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Expander class, it has native function for collapsible panel in WPF. MSDN: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.expander.aspx.

Source StackOverflow answer: [How to create a collapsible panel in WPF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1305065/how-to-create-a-collapsible-panel-in-wpf)

However, if you want to make it customizable, use `HeaderedContentControl` class instead. MSDN: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.headeredcontentcontrol.aspx. The general idea is to modify the Content Visibility when the header is clicked.

Answer (score 0):

A quick way to achieve this is using an expander as already suggested. Edit your code to the following:

```
<Expander  Header="{Binding ElementName=dgExpander, Path=SelectedItem.Name}" >
   <DataGrid Name="dgExpander" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=ProductList, Source={StaticResource MainWindowViewModel}}" AutoGenerateColumns="false" Width="500" Height="80">
      <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Name" Binding="{Binding Name}" Width="100" />
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Code" Binding="{Binding Code}" Width="100" />
      </DataGrid.Columns>
   </DataGrid>
</Expander>
```

this can be an example to work on.
HTH