# Replacement control for ExpandableListView(Android)/UITableView(iOS) in Windows phone 8.1

Tags: c#, controls, windows-phone-8.1

Do we have any replacement control for `[ExpandableListView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ExpandableListView.html)(Android) / [UITableView](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/uitableview_class/index.html)(iOS) in Windows Phone 8.1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any Control that supports `Grouping` should do the trick.

I would use either a `ListView` or a `GridView`.  Here are MSDN links, pay attention to the `HeaderItemTemplate` / `ItemTemplate`.

[How to Group Items in a List or Grid](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/hh780627.aspx)

To do what you want to do would require quite a bit of MVVM binding and `VisualState` modification.

---

Another option would to create your own List with a collapsible `<StackPanel>` as its DataTemplate.

My sample solution to collapse a ListBox, you can modify that to include another List as well.

[Listbox Collapse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26064920/c-sharp-xaml-listbox-collapse-when-clicked/26071024#26071024)

Comment: Can we add event on selection of group or Item in group? Can we collapse groups on click or by default make it collapse?

Comment: @AnkushMadankar changes in selection are handle through the `SelectionChanged` event for most controls.  It won't collapse by default, you will need to heavily modify the `<Style>`, `VisualState`, and the `ItemContainerStyle` as well.  So it's not a very trivial thing to do.

Comment: @AnkushMadankar like I said before, you can always do a ItemControl with a nested <StackPanel>s, clicking on the top <StackPanel> will hide/show it's child <StackPanel>.  When done correctly it will collapse and bring up any other items or expand and push any other items down -- hence the name "Stack" -- Panel.