# Create a resizeable (expand+collapse) TextBlock control

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-runtime, windows-phone-8.1, winrt-xaml

I was trying to create a control with two `TextBlock>`s, having a "Show more" & "Show less" functionality. Considering an initial threshold `X`, if the `TextBlock`'s height is bigger than the Threshdold, the `TextBlock` will be resized to the Threshold's value (collapse till hits the value). Clicking again, would expand the `TextBlock` to  `MaxHeight="Auto"`.

Here's what I tried so far :

```
<StackPanel>
    <TextBlock x:Name="ResizeableTextBlock"
               Text="{Binding Description}" 
               TextWrapping="Wrap" MaxHeight="{Binding ResizeThreshold}"/>
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding ResizeLabel}" 
               Foreground="{StaticResource PhoneAccentBrush}"
               Tapped="OnResizeLabelTapped"/>
</StackPanel>
```

and the `Tapped` event handler would look like this :

```
private void OnResizeLabelTapped(object sender, TappedRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if (ResizeableTextBlock.ActualHeight > viewModel.ResizeThreshold)
    {
        ResizeableTextBlock.MaxHeight = ResizeThreshold;
        ResizeLabel = ShowLessLabel;
    }
    else if (ResizeableTextBlock.ActualHeight < viewModel.ResizeThreshold)
    {
        ResizeableTextBlock.ClearValue(MaxHeightProperty);
        ResizeLabel = ShowMoreLabel;
    }
}
```

The issue with this approach is that the `ActualHeight` of an element is most likely slightly different than the `Height` assigned initially to the element.
For example, setting `Height = 200`, and then querying the `ActualHeight` value, results in a value similar to `201.00747494...` because of all the calculations done by the system and the layout.

Any ideas on a more reliable approach?

P.S. There's also a nice property `MaxLines` which gives exactly what I need but going with this path is not quite helpful, because I still need to determine initally whether the "Show More" or "show Less" has to be applied and... `MaxLines` is just a setter, there isn't something like "CurrentLines" getter to compare with.

Comment: I did a very similar thing over here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26064920/c-sharp-xaml-listbox-collapse-when-clicked/26071024#26071024,  get rid of that else if, it's either one or the other.  I used a Border instead.